# Casperjs unexpected exit

Tags: javascript, casperjs, exit

I am trying to download files from multiple pages. I thought i would click on `next` button until it become disabled, but for some reason casperjs stops after 2 pages (there are 4 pages till the end).

I am new to casperjs, so it seem i just don't understand some basic concept.

### Code

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
casper.on('load.finished', function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        this.echo ("Failed to load page.");
    }
    else {
        //download_files_from_page();
         this.echo ("1");
         casper.click("#MainContent_btnNext1");
 }
});
casper.start('http://matrixcatalog.co.il/NBCompetitionRegulations.aspx');
casper.run();
```

### Expected output

> 1 1 1 1

### Actual output

> 1 1

Answer (score 2):

You're probably exiting too early. If CasperJS runs out of steps to execute, it will automatically exit. Only `then*`, `wait*` and `run` functions add a step to the queue.

### Simple fix #1:

Change `casper.click(...)` to `casper.thenClick(...)`.

### Simple fix #2:

Pass an empty function to `run`:

```
casper.run(function(){});
```

and exit before clicking:

```
if(!this.exists("#MainContent_btnNext1")) {
    this.exit();
    return;
}
```

### Proper fix:

You should use a proper recursive iteration, because the other approaches are based on assumption that may not be true for future versions of CasperJS.

```
function handlePage(status) {
    if (!this.exists(nextSelector)) {
        this.echo("finished");
    } else {
        // do something
        this.thenClick(nextSelector, handlePage);
    }
});
casper.start(url, handlePage).run();
```

Comment: Hi Artjom.  Thank a lot for your help. Unfortunately none of the fixes worked for me.
first one  it exited after one iteration.
second fix: casper did not exited, but it seem load.finished callback was fired only once. 
third fix: exit after 2 iterations.

Comment: I forgot something important for the "proper fix". Unfortunately, the site doesn't work for me in Firefox, so I can't test how it behaves. When you click on the "next" button, is a new page loaded or is only the table reloaded asynchronously?

Comment: New page is loaded. When i click javascript send post request to server.